# Im writting a puzzle program that is not giving me back any output

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

If  a   puzzle  is  solvable,   the getSolution method  returns a   String  containing  the indices visited.
Thus,   for the first   puzzle, it  would   return  [0, 3, 2, 5, 7, 8].

```
import java.util.*;
public class JumpPuzzle {

private final List<Integer> board;
private final List<Integer> visitedIndices = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public JumpPuzzle(List<Integer> board) {
    this.board = board;
}

public boolean canSolve() {
    return getSolution(0);
}

private boolean getSolution(int index) {
    int lastIndex = board.size() - 1;
    if(index == lastIndex) {
        return true;
    }

    if(index < 0 || index > lastIndex || visitedIndices.contains(index)) {
        return false;
    }

    visitedIndices.add(index);

    int step = board.get(index);
    return getSolution(index + step) || getSolution(index - step);
}

Puzzle puzzle = new Puzzle(Arrays.asList(5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0));
System.out.println("Puzzle is solvable: " + puzzle.canSolvable() ? "yes" : "no"); 
  }
```

I cant fix the identifier expected and Im not getting any output.   every   element of  the puzzle  array   is  used    and that    the integers    in  the array   are 
positive,   except  the rightmost   one,    which   is  zero,   and the start   index   is  not out of  bounds. The 
leftmost    number  is  at  index   0   in  the array.

Comment: "If a puzzle is solvable, the getSolution method returns a String containing the indices visited" `private boolean getSolution(int index)` I think you have a problem / implementation mismatch.

Comment: Statements must be inside methods.

Comment: "I cant fix the identifier expected" Is this an error message? Can you include the error message?

Comment: Assuming that the last two lines are placed in a correct place, I guess you realized that you are calling `Puzzle` and not `JumpPuzzle`. Also, the printing of canSolvable (canSolve?) should go between braces:  `System.out.println("Puzzle is solvable: " + (puzzle.canSolvable() ? "yes" : "no"));`

Comment: How are you even _running_ this?!

Answer (score 0):

Okay... where to start.

First, your problem statement and your implementation don't mix together.

> If a puzzle is solvable, the getSolution method returns a String (...)

Your `getSolution` method returns a boolean.

Second, you have these two lines of code...

```
Puzzle puzzle = new Puzzle(Arrays.asList(5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0));
System.out.println("Puzzle is solvable: " + puzzle.canSolvable() ? "yes" : "no");
```

And as far as I can see, they're not in a method or static block. You're declaring that a `JumpPuzzle` has a `puzzle` attribute, and placing a `System.out.println` outside of a method body is a syntax error.

Thirdly, you've named your class `JumpPuzzle`, but are creating a `Puzzle` instance. Maybe you forgot to include the code for the `Puzzle` class, which would be a subclass of `JumpPuzzle`, but it seems more likely that the `puzzle` variable should be of type `JumpPuzzle` instead.

Fourth, again, this doesn't apply if there's a class `Puzzle` that extends `JumpPuzzle`, but I don't see a method `canSolvable`. (used here: `System.out.println("Puzzle is solvable: " + puzzle.canSolvable() ? "yes" : "no");`). You do have a method `canSolve`, so this seems like a typo?

I recommend taking a detailed look at the error messages your compiler provides to you when compiling your code. I haven't checked for everything, there might still be issues after fixing my four points.